# Optimizing Portfolio Return by Targeting Variance

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio, optimization, markowitz, self-study

I understand Markowitz and targeting returns to minimize our variance. I know this optimization problem well and its constraints. However when the reverse scenario is to be considered I get very confused. How do I mathematically show optimal portfolio weights when I want to **target my variance** to maximize my return?

I am supposed to use a Lagrangian method but all I get is *lambda* in relation to some optimal weight. I know that the optimal variance condition should be **1Tranpose** * **covariance matrix** * **1** where **1** is the ones matrix. I can mathematically show this but cannot understand how this optimal variance relates to the optimal weights and portfolio return.[image]

Comment: I assume this is homework or self-study? If so, please tag with self-study.

Comment: @kurtosis thanks for the suggestion